# Calculator vs SQL Server giving different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple calculation `sum(eom_count)/ 3`. It results in a value of 82, rather than 84.

When I use a calculator, I get 84:

```
select sum(eom_mbr_count ) from elig table = 252
select sum(eom_mbr_count/3) from elig table = 82
```

Calculator on computer `252/3 = 84`, I know 84 is correct, your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: My psychic powers tells me that the field `eom_mbr_count` is an integer field. This means `eom_mbr_count/3` will do integer division, which will truncate. Example, 10/3 will yield 3, not 3.3333333333333333............ Try doing `select sum(eom_mbr_count)/3 from elig_table` instead. This will do the integer division at the end.

Comment: As an example of what I meant by the above. If you have 9 rows all with the value 1 in that field, `1/3` as an integer division will yield 0, which means summing that 9 times will still yield 0. However, if you first sum the field, which yields 9, and then divide by 3, you will get 3. You can also try dividing by 3.0, but then you're most likely propagating floating point errors for all rows instead, better to divide at the end.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you should post this as an answer

Comment: once i find the check mark, I will close ... lol

Comment: Thanks, once again. once i find that solved check mark, i will check as answer, i don't come out here that much

Comment: I'm lost . . . 252 *is* divisible by 3, so 252 / 3 = 84.  It would have to be a floating point field for the value to be off.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but it's not SUM(col)/3, it's SUM(col/3). So instead of 252/3, it's something else, like (200/3 + 44/3 + 8/3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were unlucky in that the result of your sum was a number wholly divisible by 3, otherwise you might've spotted the problem yourself and at least wondered why that is.

As is now evident by my comments and your reply on your question, your field is an integer field, and when you divide one integer by another integer you get "integer division" which does not yield a floating point number, it yields another integer.

As an example, if you divide `1/3`, most programming languages and database engines with a hard separation between integers and floating point numbers will give you a result of 0, not 0.333333333333..... If an integer division will yield another integer, it cannot yield .333333333333, it will always yield a whole integer, which in this case will be 0.

So what happened in your case is that you have 1 or more rows which, when your `eom_mbr_count` field is divided by 3, using integer division, loses the fractional part, and thus produces a result that looks wrong.

As an example of this, consider having 9 rows in your database with the value 1 in the `eom_mbr_count` field for all those rows.

If you sum the field for all the rows, you get 9. However, if you sum the `eom_mbr_count/3` result for all those rows you will get 0, because each individual row result will produce 0.

The simplest way to fix this is to postpone the division until you've summed all the rows:

```
select sum(eom_mbr_count)/3 from elig table = 82
```

Notice that I moved `/3` out of the parenthesis there, which means will divide the *sum* by 3, not sum *each element divided by 3*.

Another solution might be to divide by `3.0`, which will produce a floating point division, but again I would advise to use the above approach, to avoid propagating floating point errors for each rows.

Comment: Dividing inside sum really do produce errors. I got 76399150184002.960409 instead of 76399150184010 on my test. Not to mention it is 2x-3x slower. In case of int overflow you can cast to bigint inside sum.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does *integer* division, so `1/2` is `0` rather than 0.5.  Just divide by 3.0 instead of 3:

```
select sum(eom_mbr_count / 3.0) /
from elig
```